# Multiple paths to BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS

Tags: scripting

I would like to have two folders where i can put scripts and addons that will be loaded at start time with blender.

for example if its possible to add two paths to BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

To use multiple directories on Windows, i edited the file `2.78\scripts\addon_utils.py` and added my path in the function `paths()` beginning at line 48

```
def paths():
    # RELEASE SCRIPTS: official scripts distributed in Blender releases
    addon_paths = _bpy.utils.script_paths("addons")

    # CONTRIB SCRIPTS: good for testing but not official scripts yet
    # if folder addons_contrib/ exists, scripts in there will be loaded too
    addon_paths += _bpy.utils.script_paths("addons_contrib")

+   # ADDITIONAL SCRIPTS: for development 
+   addon_paths += [r"C:\Users\plu\Documents\Blender\pyScripts\dev\addons"]
    return addon_paths
```

I also edited the file `2.78\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_userpref.py` and modified the `draw` method of the `USERPREF_PT_addons` panel beginning at line 1243, so that the addons from the folder will show up under the *User* Filter

```
def draw(self, context):
    import os
    import addon_utils

    layout = self.layout

    userpref = context.user_preferences
    used_ext = {ext.module for ext in userpref.addons}

    userpref_addons_folder = os.path.join(userpref.filepaths.script_directory, "addons")
    scripts_addons_folder = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', "addons")
+   scripts_dev_folder = r"C:\Users\plu\Documents\Blender\pyScripts\dev\addons"

+   scripts_user_folders = userpref_addons_folder, scripts_addons_folder, scripts_dev_folder

        # check if addon should be visible with current filters
        if ((filter == "All") or
            (filter == info["category"]) or
            (filter == "Enabled" and is_enabled) or
            (filter == "Disabled" and not is_enabled) or
-           (filter == "User" and (mod.__file__.startswith((userpref_addons_folder, scripts_addons_folder))))
+           (filter == "User" and (mod.__file__.startswith(scripts_user_folders)))
            ):
```

On Linux i create symbolic links in the addons folder. It is explained in this [video](https://youtu.be/mYrPqrFY7mA?list=PLa1F2ddGya_8FBk61qbCdRu-otyPzFfDF&t=401)