# Can I have a scripts folder relative to my portable Blender, but outside of its folder?

Tags: add-on, customization, path

I'm currently on Windows 10. I have a portable version of blender 2.80, and I would like to use relative paths for the scripts folder in order to keep my addons separate from the bundled ones. My solution so far has been symlinking my addons folder to the AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.80/scripts folder, and that works fine, but it's not fully portable. In the preferences > file paths, for scripts, putting // followed by anything seems to not work at all. Only direct paths seem to work. Optimally, it would be //../../stuffhere/addons. The shift click on the folder icon in the preferences page brings up the correct folder, but no new addons show up in the addon section.

Edit: I found this answer, but it still relies on direct paths.
[Multiple paths to BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66497/multiple-paths-to-blender-user-scripts)

Edit: I also found this one which seem relevant. [How do I change the location of the "Temp" folder to be a relative path?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91234/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-the-temp-folder-to-be-a-relative-path)?
Unless I'm reading it wrong, this one means that some file paths in the Blender settings don't work with relative paths.

The relative paths would just be a convenient way to get a portable separate addons folder. If there is another way, I would love to know. The end goal is to make updating portable versions easier. It's a pain to have to dig around for only the files related to my addons in the main folder and move them to the new versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple paths to BLENDER\_USER\_SCRIPTS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66497/multiple-paths-to-blender-user-scripts)

Comment: In the answer on [Multiple paths to BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69607/599), you are setting the `addon_path` directly in python, so you can use python to de-relativeize the path first (with [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path%20abspath#os.path.abspath) for e.g.). That said, it requires modifying some python sources in the blender package, which sort of defeats the point if you are looking to have the same scripts picked up by different versions of blender.